# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' [convert data type]

Tags: python

I was trying to multiply 2 data from a data frame, but it gives a **TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'** when I run the code. May I know how to convert the data frame data type from 'pandas.core.series.Series' to 'int'?

```
def generatePortfolioStatement(stock):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = stock[1:],columns = stock[0])
    local_df = df
    sum_mp = str(100) + "%"
    local_df["Total Invested"] = local_df["Qty"]  *local_df["BoughtPrice"]
    sum_ti = local_df["Total Invested"].sum()
    local_df["Invested Portfolio Size"] = ((local_df["Total Invested"] / sum_ti) * 100).round(0).astype(str) + "%"
    local_df["Total Market Value"] = local_df["Qty"] * local_df["MarketPrice"]
    sum_mv = local_df["Total Market Value"].sum()
    local_df["Profit/Loss"] = local_df["Total Market Value"] - local_df["Total Invested"]
    sum_pl = local_df["Profit/Loss"].sum()
    local_df["Market Portfolio Size"] = ((local_df["Total Market Value"] / sum_mv) * 100).round(0).astype(str) + "%"
    sum_row = {"No":" ","Company":" ","Cap":" ","Qty":" ","BoughtPrice":" ","MarketPrice":"Sum","Total Invested":sum_ti,"Invested Portfolio Size":" ","Total Market Value":sum_mv,"Profit/Loss":sum_pl,"Market Portfolio Size":sum_mp}
    local_df = local_df.append(sum_row, ignore_index = True)
    return local_df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
local_df["Qty"] = local_df["Qty"].astype(int)
local_df["BoughtPrice"] = local_df["BoughtPrice"].astype(int)
local_df["Total Invested"] = local_df["Total Invested"].astype(int)
local_df["Total Market Value"] = local_df["Total Market Value"].astype(int)
local_df["MarketPrice"] = local_df["MarketPrice"].astype(int)
```

This will convert your data column type to int from str

Comment: I have tried this method but it did't work and still generating the same error.

Comment: You should use this for all your columns. Please check the updated answer

Comment: yes i managed to solve this error using the .astype(int) for all the columns. Thank you!